# pass data without adding into url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$stateProvider.state('academicYearCatalogue', {
    url: '/academicYearCatalogue/:programKey',
    templateUrl: 'app-ace/academicYearCatalogue/views/academicYearCatalogue-detail.tpl.html',
    controller: 'AcademicYearCatalogueDetailCtrl as AcademicYearCatalogueDetailCtrlVM',
    resolve: {
        academicYearList: ['AcademicYearService', '$stateParams',
          function (AcademicYearService, $stateParams) {
            var obj = {
                programKey: $stateParams.programKey,
            }

            return AcademicYearService.getAllYear(obj)
            .$promise.then(function (result) {
                return result.data;
            });

        }]
    }
});
```

i want to pass data between controllers via ui-router v 0.2.8 but don't want to add to url, how do i achieve this?
          this programkey is coming from some controller and i want to use this in resolve but not with url.how do i achieve this.

angular js version is 1.2.20

Comment: You don't. It would be a terrible idea. Refreshing the page would not allow you to display anything anymore because you wouldn't be able to find the programKey anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Using ***params*** property of state you can pass the data as given below

params: {
        user_desisred_params_name: null,
}

So the complete code is given below-

$stateProvider.state('academicYearCatalogue',
   {    url: '/academicYearCatalogue',
        templateUrl: 'app-ace/academicYearCatalogue/views/academicYearCatalogue-detail.tpl.html',
    controller: 'AcademicYearCatalogueDetailCtrl as AcademicYearCatalogueDetailCtrlVM',
    resolve: {

```
    academicYearList: ['AcademicYearService', '$stateParams',
      function (AcademicYearService, $stateParams) {
        var obj = {
            programKey: $stateParams.programKey,
        }

        return AcademicYearService.getAllYear(obj)
        .$promise.then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
        });

    }]
},
```

params:{
       yourKey : programKey
   }

});